# Modify Highslide Behavior - (on click - next)

Tags: highslide

Can anyone suggest a way to modify Highslide so that when a user click on an image in will go to the next image as opposed to closing? I'd also like to disable the off image click which closes the image as well.

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0):

For "click for next," add this to your highslide configuration file (loaded after the script), or put it in the body of the page in  tags (also after the script is loaded):

```
hs.Expander.prototype.onImageClick = function() {
    return hs.next();
}
```

You'll also want to change the tooltip for hs.lang.restoreTitle.

This requires highslide-full.js.

Comment: OK I've got it.  I misread your post.  Thanks so much for your time!

Answer (score 0):

For preventing "close" upon clicking outside the image, use hs.dimmingOpacity greater than 0, then add this to your config:

```
hs.onDimmerClick = function() {
    return false;
}
```

If you don't want any background dimming, set hs.dimmingOpacity to some tiny value, like 0.01.

This requires highslide-full.js.

Comment: The "close" code is working just fine, thanks. I'm not 100% sure where to insert the "click for next" code. I don't see a highslide config file. And are you referring to the main html page? Thanks! – user2205027 1 min ago edit

Comment: You can put this kind of stuff between <script> tags in the main HTML (in the <head> section), after your call to highslide-full.js. It's easier to maintain the page, however, if you put these kinds of settings in a separate highslide-config.js file (without <script> tags, of course), then just load it into the page, exactly the same way you load highslide-full.js. Just make sure you load the config file after you load the regular script file, since the config entries are intended to override what's in the regular script.